# If $K$ is the smallest subspace such that $W+K=V$, then $W\oplus K = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following theorem is from my textbook:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $W,K$ be subspaces of $V$, the following claims are equivalent:

> 1. $V=W \oplus K$

> 2. K is the largest subspace of $V$ with the property $W\cap K = \{0\}$

> 3. K is the smallest subspace of $V$ with the property $W+ K = V$

I'm having problems showing $3)\Rightarrow 1)$; since $W+K=V$, we only have to show that $W\cap K = \{0\}$, I tried it by contradiction, then we have that

\begin{align}
V &= W + K\\
\\
&= {\rm span}(W\cup K)\\
\\
&= {\rm span}\big(W\cup[K-W]\big)\\
\\
&= {\rm span}(W) + {\rm span}(K-W)\\
\\
&= W + {\rm span}(K-W)
\end{align}

then ${\rm span}(K-W)$ is a subspace of $V$ with the property that $W + {\rm span}(K-W) = V$ and ${\rm span}(K-W)\subseteq K$, at this point, I'm not sure how to use $W\cap K\not=\{0\}$ to show that ${\rm span}(K-W)\not= K$ and then get the contradiction (K is not the smallest subspace of $V$ with the property $W + K = V$). I'm in the correct way? Can you give me some hint?

EDIT: I'm not allowed to assume Axiom of Choice.

Comment: By chance is the book *Álgebra Lineal* by Hugo Rincón? Hint: let $H$ be a supplement for $W\cap K$ in $K$ (i.e. $K=(W\cap K)\oplus H$).

Comment: What results do you assume, and do you have the axiom choice? Without choice we'll get troubles to get a supplement of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @blargoner Yes, it is. This theorem appears early in the book, so we can't assume that for every subspace $K$ there exists another subspace $W$ such that $V = K\oplus W$, since it is a theorem proven in later sections.

Comment: Let $0 \ne x \in W \cap K \supsetneq \{0\}$. Then $W + (K \setminus \text{span}\{x\}) = V$, but $K \setminus \text{span}\{x\} \subsetneq K$ is a smaller set.

Comment: @JoeShmo That is not valid, since $K\backslash\text{span}\{x\}$ is not a subspace of $V$.

Comment: @JorgeS., whoops, you're right. What I meant is the following: extend $\{x\}$ to a basis for $K$, $B$. Then $V = W + \text{span}(B \setminus \{x\})$, where $\text{span}(B \setminus \{x\}) \subsetneq K$ is a smaller vector space.

Comment: @JoeShmo I'm sorry, I didn't mention it, but I'm not allowed to assume Axiom of Choice, so we can't assume that $\{x\}$ can be extended to a basis for $K$.

Comment: @JorgeS. The author of this textbook seems like a crazy person. :)

Comment: Are you sure the writer said that the axiom of choice is not assumed? Since linear algebra is a relatively elementary course, maybe the axiom of choice is assumed, but the writer did not especially mention it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should hold without the axiom of choice. If we take $W = \langle v \rangle$, then $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$ implies that any one-dimensional subspace has a complementary subspace. In the general (not necessarily one-dimensional) case this does imply AC

Answer (score 1):

First, I think $K\cap W\neq\{0\}\not\Longrightarrow span(K-W)\neq K$. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $K=\{(x,y,z): x=0\}$, $W=\{y=0\}$. then $K=span((0,1,1),(0,0,1))\subseteq span(K-W)\subseteq K$, which implies $span(K-W)=K$, a counterexample.

Next this is an alternative method: If $K\cap W\neq \{0\}$, then let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $K\cap W$, $\{e_i\}\cup \{f_i\}$ and $\{e_i\}\cup \{g_i\}$ respctively be a basis of $K$ and $W$, then $\bar{K}$, the subspace of $K$ generated by $\{g_i\}$, shall satisfy $W+\bar{K}=V$, contradiction.

Comment: I tried it by contradiction, so what I'd like to prove is $K\cap W \not= \{0\} \ \Rightarrow \ \text{span}(K-W) \not= K$ and as I mentioned, I'm not allowed to assume Axiom of Choice, so we can't assume that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: @JorgeS. Sorry, this is a typo. $K\cap W\neq \{0\}$ does not imply $span(K-W)\neq K$, as the counterexample I mentioned in my question.